# How to stop a javascript function after a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a html and javascript game. I have a title picture of my company but need to display of for only a few seconds how should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/D6PQ3/)**. Try setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    alert("Hello");
    //your code here...
}, 3000);
```

Comment: That won't work beacuse rat will bring it back to that function every few seconds I need it to show once and stop

Comment: the code will be run only onced. what are you talking about is setInterval.